# Javascript validator

Tags: javascript, validation

Hi I'm trying to validate the option that the user check and if they didn't checked anything in the page then will display an error message and let them check before it will continue

here is my code

```
for (var j=0;j<f10; j++ )
{
    if (document.pizza.field10[j].checked == true)
      { check2 ++ ; }
}// for ends heree

if (check2 == 0 )
            {
        alert("Error!!: Please select atleast one topping for Pizza.");
  document.pizza.field10.focus();
  return false;
            }

/*Field05 Validation Ends Here*/
```

and `var f10 = document.pizza.field10.length ;// field05` this is the total length and `f10` is the variable.

I don't know what is wrong even the user didn't check the option it still continue

Thanks

EDIT here is the html code

```
<p>Toppings:</p>
<table width="400" class="toppings">
<tr>

<td><label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="field10" value="chicken"  />
  Chicken</label></td>

<td><label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="field10" value="beef" />
  Beef</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="field10" value="green pepper"  />

  Green Pepper</label></td>

<td><label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="field10" value="olives"  />
  Olives</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="field10" value="onions" />
  Onions</label></td>

<td><label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="field10" value="red pepper"  />
  Red Pepper</label></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

EDIT2: here is the form tag

```
<form name='pizza' id='pizza' method='post'
               action='https://cs.senecac.on.ca/~int222/cgi-bin/assign3.cgi'
               onsubmit='return FormValidation();'>
```

and here is the submit button

```
<p> <input class="button" name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />   <input class="button" name="reset" type="reset" value="Reset" />

</p></div>
```

Comment: Can you add in the HTML that this script is running on? my hunch is that `field10[j]` is not quite doing what you want it to

Comment: @Chris I've added the html code above thanks!

Comment: Is the `f` supposed to be there? `for (var j=0;j<f10; j++ )`

Comment: @Shredder I've edit my post `f10` is a variable sorry about that

Comment: add the form tag and submit button. Then add your script function and the var declaration to f10...

Comment: where does `pizza` come from in your `document.pizza...` code?

Comment: @GabrielGartz I've added that code above.

Comment: its possible to optimize your code but probabli is a html syntax error like. You need to re-check your form inside html code. Im on cell and will be hard to rewrite your code here

Comment: are you positive `check2` is set to `0` before this code executes? Also, don't name your input button `Submit`. I've seen this cause issues. Call it `btnSubmit`, or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was

```
document.pizza.field10.focus();
```

I think, you cannot focus buttons or checkbox fields :) 
Thanks all for help.

Comment: The problem is that you need to focus a particular instance of a checkbox or button. `field10` is actually an array of DOM elements, not a particular one.  You can see a working example where both a button and a checkbox gain focus programatically (using jQuery but the process is similar for pure javascript) at http://jsfiddle.net/mHKGK/

Answer (score 1):

Aside from being positive `check2` is set to `0` before your code executes and possibly re-naming your submit button (per my comment). I would try using the debugging tool [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) to step through your `FormValidation()` function to make sure your code is actually retrieving the DOM nodes and see where `check2` is getting incremented.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your code to something like [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qa6PY/)

The important part being this:

```
    var fields = document.getElementsByName("field10");
```

( And the complete code here for when the JS Fiddle Expires )

```
var check2 = 0;
var fields = document.getElementsByName("field10");

for (var j = 0; j < fields.length - 1; j++) {
    if (fields[j].checked == true) {
        check2++;
    }
} // for ends heree
if (check2 == 0) {
    alert("Error!!: Please select at least one topping for Pizza.");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This is Ali(actually i asked him to post this question for me) I tried the code above with -1 but no luck -- same error exist.... please guide